# Attach matplot.figure.Figure to pyplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

TL;DR:
I would like to output a matplotlib.figure.Figure instance with matplotlib.pyplot.

Long version:
I have a function that returns a matplotlib.figure.Figure instance. The function adds some data to the figure, but does not yet show the graph. Thus, it is possible to decide afterwards what backend should be used to output the figure. I was able to find out how to do draw the graph with tkinter, and it shouldn't be much of a problem to do the same with other backends. But, and that is my problem, I couldn't find out how to draw the figure with a simple pyplot command. How should I do this?

Comment: if you'd use jupyter notebook, you would run `%matplotlib inline` before creating the figure. it will then be automatically displayed.

Comment: Yes, with jupyter, it seems to work too, but is there any way to do it with the default IDLE?

Comment: With pyplot you would need to first select the backend (or trust the automatic choice),  then create the figure and show it.

Comment: Do you have documentation on this?

Comment: No, this is not really documented. Implicitely you see it from the fact that the documentation only shows cases where pyplot is used from the start, or cases where the figure is attached to a canvas outside of pyplot.